# Consider the sets X = {a, b, c} and Y = {1, 2}. How many functions are there with domain X and codomain Y?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Consider the sets X = {a, b, c} and Y = {1, 2}. How many functions are there with domain X and codomain Y ? Draw an arrow diagram for each such function.

Just an interesting problem I am trying out of interest.

I have considered possibilities such as the function being:

f: X --> Y, f(x) = Number of factors of x.

However I have not been able to come up with a definite number of functions.

Comment: $2$ choices for where to send $a$ times $2$ choices for where to send $b$ times  $2$ choices for where to send $c$

Comment: You should learn to be more precise. You did not state anything about $a$, $b$ or $c$, even though you were talking about factors.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $a,b,c$ are distinct the answer is $8$. For each of the points $a,b,c$ there are two choices, so the total numbe is $(2)(2)(2)=8$.

The functions are

$a \to 1, b\to 1, c\to 1$

$a \to 1, b\to 1, c\to 2$

$a \to 1, b\to 2, c\to 1$

$a \to 1, b\to 2, c\to 2$

$a \to 2, b\to 1, c\to 1$

$a \to 2, b\to 1, c\to 2$

$a \to 2, b\to 2, c\to 1$

$a \to 2, b\to 2, c\to 2$

Comment: Arrow diagrams? Could you name the functions?

Comment: @global05 I have edited my answer.

Comment: But what are the functions? i.e. x^2 + 1? # of Factors?

Comment: A function assigns a unique value to each member of the domain. A function need not be given by any formula..

Comment: global05 you can define functions just by defining there values for any element of X. There is no possible formula here (like polynomial or whatsoever)

Comment: @dallonsi is incorrect, any function on a finite set can be written as a polynomial, using interpolation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Comment: @pre-kidney The question does not even say that $a,b,c$ are numbers. They may be donkey,monkey and buffalo!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy your comment is correct but misses the point - of course the function can be written as a polynomial, after choosing an arbitrary embedding (i.e. labeling) of the set in $\mathbb R$ (or any other field with cardinality at least as large as the set). The point (as I see it) is that any finite function can be given an algebraic expression, which is my interpretation of what global05 was confused about

Answer (score 1):

Generalization for finite sets X ans Y: the answer is the cardinal of Y to the cardinal of X. Indeed, for each element in X there are cardinal of Y possible images.

Answer (score 1):

In general for sets $A$ and $B$, the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ is denoted $B^A$ and has cardinality $|B|^{|A|}$. Indeed, a function from $A$ to $B$ can equivalently be thought of as a sequence of elements of $B$, indexed by $A$. Each element in the sequence has $|B|$ possibilities, and there are $|A|$ elements in total, so since the choices are independent of one another, there are $|B|^{|A|}$ choices in total.

In this case, we find $2^3=8$ functions.